# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
time.text.configure(text=timeString)
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have imported module `time` which has no `text` attribute.

Since you have tagged your question with "tkinter" it seems that you are trying to update the text of a widget. You need to use the correct variable for the widget in question.